# Flutter Signing App how to slove this problem?

Tags: flutter, signing

i try to Siging my App as it is described here
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

i Add this to my command

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\MyOwnUserName\key.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

but get that displayed here

```
The "keytool" command is either misspelled or
could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your did not read the full instructions:

> The keytool command might not be in your path—it’s part of Java, which is installed as part of Android Studio.

> For the concrete path, run "flutter doctor -v" and locate the path printed after ‘Java binary at:’.

> Then use that fully qualified path replacing java (at the end) with keytool.

> If your path includes space-separated names, such as Program Files, use platform-appropriate notation for the names. For example, on Mac/Linux use Program\ Files, and on Windows use "Program Files".

That is a quote from the page you linked and it should work.

Comment: Ok i have the path and now? 

replace c:\Users\MyOwnUserName\key.jks with C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool ?

Comment: No, you should replace `keytool` with `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool`.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\MyOwnUserName\key.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key   this??? if yes not work

Comment: Did you follow the last paragraph and used quotation marks around your path with spaces?

Comment: C:\"Program Files"\Android\"Android Studio"\jre\bin\keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\MyOwnUserName\key.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key now have this but now i have a list what i need to make? i see a video on youtube its complete differed to me

Comment: I don't think the quotes work that way. `"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool"`

Comment: this works C:\"Program Files"\Android\"Android Studio"\jre\bin\keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\MyOwnUserName\key.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key but now i have a list  what do I have to choose?

Comment: -certreq
 -changealias
 -delete
 -exportcert
 -genkeypair
 -genseckey
 -gencert
 -importcert
 -importpass
 -importkeystore
 -keypasswd
 -list
 -printcert
 -printcertreq
 -printcrl          
 -storepasswd

Comment: What do you mean by "a list"?

Comment: after i add C:\"Program Files"\Android\"Android Studio"\jre\bin\keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\MyOwnUserName\key.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key i see a list with commands i postet the  commands 1 hour ago

Comment: Then I guess it did **not** work and you should try what I told you before, put the whole path to keytool in quotes.

Comment: i do it and this is the result :(

Comment: Okay, this is my last attempt at reading you the manual: put the whole path to the keytool in quotes. Like this: `"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool"` and add all the other parameters that you were given. so in the End it's `"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool" -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\MyOwnUserName\key.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key`. And obviously you have to replace `MyOwnUserName` with your actual user name on your Windows machine.